# How to create a variable with the data of a csv file stored on the local machine in Angular typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, csv, papaparse

I want to create a variable and set its value to be equal to a CSV file on the local machine. The CSV file would be coming from an API call which returns a URL. My code would then download the file, then I want to create the variable to contain the data of the CSV file, then pass that variable to a function from the library papa parse to parse it.

Would this be as simple as making an import statement such as
import * as csv from './nameofcsv.csv'?

Then assigning the variable as var csv = csv?

Answer (score 0):

if the url returns the csv you may use HttpClient like this

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {

  public apiUrl: string;
  public csv: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  myMethod() {
      return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
        .subscribe( csv => this.csv = csv);
  }
}
```